# How to store input value of dynamically created input element into one variable in react + typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My logic might seem a bit off cause I'm pretty new to react and typescript. I created an input component that generates input element according to the length of a word which comes in as props, when a user types the word, I want to be able to get the value of each input and store them into one variable, I tried concatenating the input values of the individual input element but the output still comes out individually.Thanks

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

interface Props{
  word: string,
  setScoreHandler: (event: any) => void
}

const Input: React.FC<Props> = ({word, setScoreHandler}) => {
  const [words, setWords] = useState('')
  const textArray = word.split('')

  const appendWord = (e: { target: { value: string } }) => {
    let inputValue = ''
    let inputValue1 = inputValue.concat(e.target.value)
    setWords(inputValue1)
    console.log(inputValue1)
  }


  const style: React.CSSProperties = {
    MozBoxShadow :  "inset 0 0 10px #000000",
    WebkitBoxShadow : "inset 0 0 10px #000000",
    boxShadow :  "inset 0 0 10px #000000",
  }
  return (
    <>
    {textArray.map(text => (
      <input style={style} key={text} type="text" maxLength="1" onChange={appendWord} className='w-11 h-20 bg-walnut text-center text-3xl rounded-lg ml-3 shadow-inner-lg'/>
    ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default Input
```

Comment: It's a little confusing on what your trying to do, you say words, but then your splitting into characters, not words.  What does it mean when you say the output comes out individually?, if you mean each character, then yes, as I pointed out your splitting on every char -> `'Hi'.split('')` would be `H` then `i`..

Comment: @Keith sorry for the confusion, the word is made an array to enable the input element equal the length of the word dynamically, when the user input the said word, I want to store the value of each input element into a single variable as soon as the last value is typed into the input element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `console.log(words)` is not going to give you the updated value of words, since the `setState` process is sorta async.
To track each input, you need to maybe use their indexes. I suggest modifying the jsx to

```
{textArray.map((text, index )=> (
    <input style={style} key={text} type="text" maxLength="1" onChange={e => appendWord(e, index)} className='w-11 h-20 bg-walnut text-center text-3xl rounded-lg ml-3 shadow-inner-lg'/>
))}
```

Then modify appendWord to look like:

```
const appendWord = (e: { target: { value: string } }, index: number) => {
    const newWords = words.split('');
    newWords[index] = e.target.value;
    setWords(newWords.join(''));
  }
```

To see the newly updated words, you need a `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // would only be logged when words is changed.
  console.log(words);
}, [words])
```

Hope this helps.